# Get Daily Basis Post with PostLike OrderBy

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to get Latest Post Daily Basis with Post Likes Order By Desc.

like,

```
10-Post1-20likes (18 Nov)
9-Post2-0Likes (18 Nov)
8-Post3-20Likes (17 Nov)
7-Post4-10Likes (17 Nov)
6-Post5-50Likes (16 Nov)
5-Post6-5Likes (16 Nov)
```

like this, Plz help me I Have two Model, Post and PostLike with relationship

Comment: Can you post the table structures  and also whatever you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

if the likes are in another column of posts, just do it:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->with('likes')->get();
```

If the likes are in the same column of posts, do it:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

Comment: I don't want only today post, it's also order by day wise

Comment: Just change Carbon value to your variable day value. $dateValue